# Loading image into ImageView using Glide with Uri returned from intent with action as ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am trying to show an Image in `ImageView` using Glide Library. I am using the Uri(`Intent.getData()`) returned in `OnActivityResult` to show in `ImageView`. I make an intent to select an image as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an image"),77);
```

Then the Uri returned in OnActivityResult is something like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A21300
```

In OnActivityResult I do the following thing but Image is not shown in ImageView:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Log.e("uri", uri.toString());            
addedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
GlideApp.with(this).load(uri).placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)).into(addedImageView);
```

Till now I have only seen people using Uri with 'file://' prefix but never 'content://' prefix. How can I load Image into ImageView using 'content://' uri with Glide ?

Comment: take a look https://androidxjava.blogspot.com/2016/09/android-take-image-from-camera-and.html

Comment: He is using some kbeanie library. Isn't there a way without use of any library ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

into your manifest and also you have performed runtime permission check if your targetSdk >= 23.

Moreover try using **File** instance from the **Uri** and load that

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(new File(uri.getPath())).placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)).into(addedImageView);
```

Comment: I already have that permission and the uri received is not for a file prefix but it is for content prefix. So it didn't worked.

Comment: Other Solution can be that to can get get Bitmap from the path and than set it on ImageView for more information take a look at [link]http://hmkcode.com/android-display-selected-image-and-its-real-path/

Comment: I know I can get the Bitmap but that is causing Heap to fill so much. This is the reason I want to use Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Convert **content** Path to **file** Path ,
Using this function,

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null,
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file
        // path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        try {
            int idx = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.handleException(ImageHelper.class.getName(), e);
              result = "";
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error as follows:`CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 6 columns.`